# Can't import Chrome User Data into Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, digital-ocean, vps

i'm trying to set up a VPS on DigitalOcean to run some of my Python scripts, mostly based on Selenium.

I have installed all the dependencies needed and i'm able to run a simple script with Selenium, visiting websites and getting data from them.

My problem rises when i try to import into the script my Chrome User Data, that i use in my local Windows machine to avoid having to login into websites and to avoid cookies popups.

This is the code i use to open my webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import random
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/root/userCache/xxx/User Data/") #Path to my User Data
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'/root/chromedriver')
```

As said the webdriver loads fine but the command "add_argument("--user-data-dir=/PATH/")" doesn't actually load the cache and cookies.

In my local Windows machine this line works perfectly, could the problem be that my server runs on Ubuntu? Is there another way to import the Chrome User Data into selenium on Linux?

Also, i should add that i copied the User Data folder directly from my Windows machine, if that's relevant.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem, as I am facing the same problem on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 18.04?